# database to be used for log storing

Tags: database, nosql

I am starting up with a log monitoring tool which captures audit logs,firewall logs and many other logs.I Have an issue in choosing the right kind of database for this project as number of logs generated per second is at least 500 which has to be stored.

Let's assume that this should be able to support 1BN+ log entries per month. The two factors that will likely come into play most are ability to write quickly and also the ability display reports quickly.

Comment: For software recommendations there is a sister site, here these kinds of questions are quite easily opinion based or very broad.

Answer (score 0):

A common stack used for log storing is the ELK stack composed of Elastic search, Logstash, and Kibana.

- **E**lastic search is used to store the documents and can execute queries.
- **L**ogstash monitors and parses the logs.
- **K**ibana is used to create reports based off of the data in elastic search.

There are other options out there. Splunk is a paid solution that does all of the above. Graylog is another solution that is similar to splunk.